# How can I find the greatest alpha numeric value by number

Tags: database, windows, excel, excel-formula, alphanumeric

I am trying to find a formula that will find the greatest numeric value in a column with strings of alphanumeric values. I want it to match the letters but find the greatest number within that match. E.g.

```
E
SW0044
MO0001
MO0002
MO0003
MO0004
```

So in Column 'E' I want to match the greatest `MO` number - which is MO0004 in this case. Is there anyway you can help?

Comment: What determines which prefix you want to match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a more efficient way, but here is one solution. It does not have any error checking

[image: Sample]

Cell B1 is the input for what prefix you want.

Cell B2 contains an array formula: (<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter formula)

```
=INDEX(B4:B10,MATCH(MAX(VALUE(IF(LEFT($B4:$B10,LEN($B$1))=$B$1,SUBSTITUTE(B4:B10,$B$1,""),0))),VALUE(IF(LEFT($B4:$B10,LEN($B$1))=$B$1,SUBSTITUTE(B4:B10,$B$1,""),0)),0))
```

**EDIT**
Modified to allow for variable length prefix

[image: Revised]

Answer (score 0):

In **F1** enter:

```
=LEFT(E1,2)
```

and copy down

In **G1** enter:

```
=--RIGHT(E1,4)
```

and copy down

then use the array formula:

```
=MAX(IF(F1:F5="MO",G1:G5))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.